# why cant i find PACKAGE EXPLORER in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have just installed eclipse. The thing is, I can't find package explorer in my recently installed eclipse. I have tried searching for package explorer in top right corner.

Also I tried this step:  **window->show view->package explorer**. but none works out!

Comment: window -> show view -> other -> java -> package explorer

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot find the command to show the package explorer? Or you found the command (window > show view > package explorer) but clicking on it does not show anything? In what perspective are you in?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **Window > Reset Perspective...** ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks for the tip... I moved my request for more information as a comment to the question and left my suggested fix as an answer.